# How to use bootstrap 4 in vue.js 2 without bootstrap-vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm wodering how can I integrate bootstrap 4 into my vue.js 2.6.
I know there are tons of tutorials out there but all of them either are [obsolete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSLj1h87W5Y&ab_channel=CodeInspire) in late 2020, or [require](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-using-bootstrap4) useing `bootstrap-vue` which brings a host of junk tags into the table which I abhore.

So I appreciate if you could provide a paractical full example of such integration with vanilla bootstrap 4.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 4, there is no such thing as "vanilla" bootstrap 4. Bootstrap's js is dependent on jQuery. So, in a Vue project, it's either jQuery Bootstrap or BootstrapVue (an alternative to Bootstrap's js, when you don't want jQuery as dependency). Besides, unlike jQuery Bootstrap, BootstrapVue can be set up so it only loads the specific components you use. The real problem with jQuery Bootstrap is not that it loads jQuery, but that it uses it to perform DOM changes which might conflict with Vue's changes.

Comment: In other words, BootstrapVue is significantly more "vanilla" than jQuery Bootstrap (because Vue code is, by an large, vanilla javascript). To load jQuery Bootstrap all you need is on their [getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) page. You're probably interested in how to load it using [webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vanilla bootstrap in a vue project. Just install bootstrap by running

```
npm i bootstrap popper.js jquery
```

Popper.js and jquery are dependencies of bootstrap.
In your main.js file, you import bootstrap by adding:

```
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: When you copy/paste sections from an external source, it is recommended to attribute it correctly and to place a link to the resource, in case the documentation gets updated and your answer becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Per official [Bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#components), the following components require JQuery, bootstrap.js and Popper.js:

Alerts for dismissing

Buttons for toggling states and checkbox/radio functionality

Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators

Collapse for toggling visibility of content

Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper)

Modals for displaying, positioning, and scroll behavior

Navbar for extending our Collapse plugin to implement responsive behavior

Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper)

Scrollspy for scroll behavior and navigation updates